# Characteristics of the audio file played by RestComm Media Server

Tags: restcomm

We are having some problems playing Wav files in RestComm: some of them play nicely but others sound very weird.

8KHz 
16bit
https://www.dropbox.com/s/34mmlbopdoc3uox/record_welcome16b.wav?dl=0

Is there any place where we can consult the supported specifications of the file?

Comment: [16 bit linear PCM](https://github.com/RestComm/mediaserver/blob/4.2.0.67/docs/sources-asciidoc/src/main/asciidoc/concept-chapter-Introduction_to_the_Media_Server.adoc#technical-specification-and-capacity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with A/U Law, Sample rate of 8000Hz, bit rate of 8, Mono channels.